# How to restore a soft deleted record using Laravel's Query builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have been using query builder for my project and would like to restore a soft deleted record using query builder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting

Restoring Soft Deleted Models
Sometimes you may wish to "un-delete" a soft deleted model. To restore a soft deleted model into an active state, use the restore method on a model instance:

```
$flight->restore();
```

or

```
Model::query()->restore();
```

IF you want to do it manually.. just

```
Model::whereNotNull('deleted_at')->update([
    'deleted_at' => null
]);
```

Comment: ThankYou for your response.I was wondering if there is anyother approach other than using eloquent like Query builder..

Comment: Yes !! I mean it could a raw query as well.

Comment: You cannot do `Model::restore();`. You can call it on a query builder but not the model itself.

Answer (score 7):

What soft deleting does is setting a value to `deleted_at` column and then filter records where the `deleted_at` column has a value using a global scope.

So to restore a soft deleted record all you have to do is set the `deleted_at` column to null.

As you wanted to do it using query builder

```
DB::table('table')
  ->where('id', $recordToRestoreId)
  ->update(['deleted_at' => null]);
```

If using Eloquent

```
Model::withTrashed()
     ->where('id', $recordToRestoreId)
     ->restore();
```

or if you have a model instance

```
$model->restore();
```